# Reading different data types in a single line in C#

Tags: c#, file, io, streamreader

I have a file format that goes like this:

```
14 00 1.5121
14 01 1.3922
14 02 1.2231
```

following a structure of

```
int int double
```

delimited by spaces.

Currently my code is:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("file_to_open.txt");
String buff;
while( file.peek() > 0 )
{
    buff = file.ReadLine();
}
```

However I am stuck at how to use `buff` to parse the `int int double` format automatically. Is there a function in C# that allows me to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: See `string.Split()`. That will break the string into the three parts based on the space delimiter. Then you can parse each individual part normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string line = file.ReadLine;
string[] elements = line.Split(' ');

int a = Convert.ToInt32(elements[0]);
int b = Convert.ToInt32(elements[1]);
double c = Convert.ToDouble(elements[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function in C# that allows me to do that?

If you read your file line by line and split it with white space, yes there is. You can use [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.double.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

```
string line;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("file_to_open.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //
}
```

And in this `while` statement, you can split and parse your values like;

```
var array = line.Split(null);
int firstInt = Int32.Parse(array[0]);
int firstInt = Int32.Parse(array[1]);
double firstDouble = Double.Parse(array[2]);
```

Remember, this method uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default if you don't provide then any `IFormatProvider`. If your `CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `.`, `Double.Parse` method throws `FormatException`.

But I *generally* suggest using their `TryParse` methods instead of `Parse` methods because if parsing operation will fail, this `TryParse` methods returns `false` instead of throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

First split each input line into fields:

```
string[] fields = buff.Split(' ');
```

then parse each field individually:

```
if(fields.Length < 3) throw...
int i1 = int.Parse(field[0];
int is = int.Parse(field[1];
string s = field[2];
```

Depending on the source of your file (how reliable is its contents) you should add a lot of error handling and defensive programming (use TryParse())